# How to load the kernel module to lxc container?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, lxc

lxc containers do not have their own Kernel so is there possible way to load the kernel into lxc container?

Comment: They're using host's kernel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it isn't. Modules get loaded by becoming part of the kernel's running code. As you noted, there is only one kernel, so that also means there can be only one set of modules.

In addition, even though guests/containers are using the host's kernel, LXC doesn't *allow* them to load their own modules into the host's kernel, because that would make escaping the container very easy (by loading a custom module that allows bypassing the namespace separation).